# Can't install iota_client on RPi 4

Tags: iota-network, hornet, raspberry-pi, iota.rs

As part of my PhD project, I managed to install two Hornet nodes, one on my laptop and one on my RPi 4. However, I can't install the iota_client on the RPi to start the coding process. Specifically, although I install maturin, I can't proceed with the develop and build commands. It prints that the maturin command is unknown.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

These are my setup nodes for iota.rs on the Raspberry PI 4

Let me know if these help.

## Shimmer IOTA.rs on RPI4 without venv

Debian Lite Bullseye 64bit

Source guide: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/develop/client/bindings/python/native

### Install prerequisited

`sudo apt install git python3-pip clang libdbus-1-dev libusb-dev libhidapi-dev libhidapi-hidraw0 libudev-dev`

Upgrade pip to latest version

`pip install --upgrade pip`

### Install Rust

`curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`

Reload enviroment

`source "$HOME/.cargo/env"`

### Get repo

`git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs.git`

### Build

`cd iota.rs/client/bindings/python/native`

`pip install -r requirements-dev.txt`

`pip install .`

Comment: As additional information yesterday the team released the `iota-sdk 1.0`, the first stable version of the new rust-based project. It’s a major upgrade combining iota.rs & wallet.rs, offering an efficient way to interact with nodes.

I still have to try to set ip up on a RPI4, but let me know it that works for you

Comment: Hello and sorry for not replying back all these months. Apparently, there were some issues with the available documentation back then. I had to make some modifications according to some material I found online. However, with the latest updates it installs perfectly.